# Linux security policy plugins

Tags: linux, security, sudo

The man page for `sudoers(5)` on Linux, says:

```
NAME
     sudoers — default sudo security policy plugin
```

What other "security plugins" are available for Linux systems?

Comment: Just as a vague pointer comment, `sssd` can obtain sudo rules from LDAP, though I don't know if anybody uses it for that. (And I have no idea where exactly that plugs in.)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz that is actually how the sudoers policy you set in FreeIPA works.

Comment: @l00p sudoers policy can come from a variety of sources, like LDAP or (as Ulrich pointed out) `sssd` as well. The ldap backend has been around for a while but the `sssd` one is relatively new-ish (basically implemented as the client portion of the FreeIPA architecture).

Comment: @Bratchley you all ought to write answers. If you want to collaborate one one, use the community wiki feature.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz see above comment, you ought to write that as an answer (or collaborate on one)